When inclusion between two Kobayshi hyperbolic manifolds is distance decreasing?
Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two Kobayshi hyperbolic complex-analytic manifolds such that $X \subset Y$. It is known $d_Y(x_1, x_2) \leq d_X(x_1, x_2)$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$. In other words, the inclusion $i \colon X \to Y$ is 1-Lipschitz.
If both $X$ and $Y$ are Riemann surfaces that are distinct, then the inclusion $i \colon X \to Y$ is (strictly) distance-decreasing, i.e., $d_Y(x_1, x_2) <  d_X(x_1, x_2)$ for all distinct $x_1, x_2 \in X$. Is there any other families of examples of such Kobayshi hyperbolic manifolds?

Sure, just take two open convex subsets of $\mathbb C^n$, such that one is compactly contained in the other.
